# Running Powershell function from .bat file giving blocked error?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, command-prompt

I am trying to run a simple powershell command from command prompt. Command is

> powershell -command get-help

but I am getting a blocked error message
[image]

Any suggestions to fix this will help. I am using something similar in one of my .bat file.

Comment: I suggest you contact "the Service Desk"

Comment: :) Thanks. But do you know what could be the reason ?

Comment: What happens if you run the command from the powershell directly? If that works you can start the powershell from within the script with the command and then close it back. In the error message it tells you to rerun `powershell -command` . You could as well look on [this website](https://blog.netspi.com/15-ways-to-bypass-the-powershell-execution-policy/) to see if the execution policy of the powershell is blocking the execution.

Further it would help to know if it occurs on all commands you try or just on specific ones.

Comment: What could be the reason? I guess your employer/university/parents are running Avecto Privilege Guard to restrict what you can do on your computer. Scroll down a bit and check the incredibly similar error message here  https://blog.avecto.com/2012/11/improve-security-with-challenge-response-authorization-in-privilege-guard-3-6/ and here https://blog.avecto.com/2012/03/self-provisioned-software-installation-with-privilege-guard/ (or "DefendPoint", as it apparently became)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to Avecto blocking the powershell -command. If anyone faces similar issue you can ask your sys admins to get added to Powershell Power user group (a group with no restrictions from Avecto).